# Google AdWords API - Report Definition Issue

Tags: google-ads-api

We are upgrading from the 201109 API to the 201209 one. The 201109 one could run a report and get data back for any client under an Adwords Account (MMC included).

Now, I get an error of "CUSTOMER_SERVING_TYPE_REPORT_MISMATCH" with version 201209. https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/troubleshooting?hl=en#ReportDefinitionError.CUSTOMER_SERVING_TYPE_REPORT_MISMATCH

Can anyone shed light as to why you can no longer generate a report (and how to fix) using ReportDefinitionService for clients under an MMC account?

Answer (score 2):

Even I got the same error when the client-customer-id was set to the MCC Id, but when I changed it to the client Id of a particular Adwords account, this error did not occur.

I think you cannot generate a report across all client accounts in an MCC(if you are trying to do this). You will have to generate separate reports for each client account.

Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

You could download a list of account IDs from the account hierarchy report then run your reports over each account ID. Unfortunately querying the MCC no longer works